# Twitter Bootstrap selected tab issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tabs looking like that:

```
<li class="dropdown tab">    
<a href="/Test" class="menu-url">
   Test<i>Test here</i>
</a>
</li>
```

[image]

When the current tab is selected it is looking like that:

[image]

But I am getting an issue when I am hovering selected tab, so the issue looking like that:

[image]

Is there any way I can change `<i>` background-color to match `href` background-color when hovering an active tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a transparent background

```
<li class="dropdown tab">    
<a href="/Test" class="menu-url">
   Test<i style="background:transparent">Test here</i>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: trying to set that in stylesheet but not working `a.menu-url i { background:transparent; }`

Comment: does with !important tag, nothing works too ?  background:transparent !important;